# Return TRUE for ALL when specific property is smaller then other property for both lists

Tags: c#, linq

Its hard to explain so I make a simplified data sample here:

I have here 2 lists of **different complex** type:

list1:

```
{ Id = 1 , Value = 1 }; {Id = 2 ,  Value = 2 }; { Id = 3 , Value = 1.5}
```

list2

```
{ Id = 1 , Value = 1 }; {Id = 2 ,  Value = 2 }; { Id = 3 , Value = 1.5}
```

A comparison of both lists should return TRUE as each value of Value property is equal in both lists.

If just one of the Value properties value differs then the whole result must be FALSE.

How can I do that with linq preferd?

Comment: You have "when specific property is smaller then other property" in title and "Value property is equal in both lists...If just one of the Value properties value differs then the whole result must be FALSE." in your body. What is actual comparison logic?

Comment: Are lists guaranteed to be sorted by Id?

Comment: Do you need to check corresponding values by list position or ID? What are expected results for comparison of `{ Id = 1 , Value = 1 }, { Id = 2 ,  Value = 2 }` and `{ Id = 2 , Value = 1 }, { Id = 1 ,  Value = 2 }`? And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, with LINQ's [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var result = list1.Zip(list2, (l1, l2) => l1.Value == l2.Value).All(x => x);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform this check by `Id` property, then [`GroupJoin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you are looking for.
It lets you group two different collections by selector and then join them:

```
bool ComplexCollectionValuesAreEqual(List<ComplexItem1> list1, List<ComplexItem2> list2)
{
    try
    {
        var grouped = list1.GroupJoin(list2, x => x.Id, x => x.Id, 
            (outer, inners) => outer.Value == inners.Single().Value);

        return grouped.All(x => x);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException) // for .Single() fail case
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can apply other comparison logic in the last lambda of `GroupJoin`, for example `outer.Value <= inners.Single().Value` to check if all Values in `item1` are equal or less than corresponding values in `item2`.

Note that in this implementation it will return false, if there is no object with such ID in `list2` collection. You may want to throw exceptions instead, if you always except it to exist.

Comment: It seems that the OP is interested about differences in the Value property not in the ID property. Your solution could have all the same Value but an ID different and the result will be false, but the OP expects true because all the Values are equal. (At least this is what I have understood from the question)

Comment: @Steve My solution checks if `Value` properties are equal for objects of two different types with the same IDs. As I have understood from the OPs question, that's what he wants. Let's clarify it.

Comment: Yes I have just read your comments above in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isTrue = list1.Select((z, i) => z.Id != list2[i].Id || z.Value != list2[i].Value).Count() == 0;
```

**If the collections are not sorted**

```
bool isTrue = list1.Where(x =>  list2.First(y => y.Id == x.Id).Value != x.Value ).Count() == 0;
```

**If the items should not have duplicates and count should be equal**

```
bool isTrue = list1.Where(x => list2.First(y => y.Id == x.Id).Value == x.Value).Count() == list2.Count && list2.Count == list1.Count;
```